# Find a maximum product $c_1\cdot c_2\cdots c_n$ such that the sum is $136$

Tags: calculus

I need to ***find the maximum*** over all possible products $c_1\cdot c_2\cdots c_n$, where $n$ **varies over all positive integers**. And all $c_i$'s are **any positive real** number satisfying $\sum c_i = 136$

First:

I try to find $n$ such that $\displaystyle \frac{n(n+1)}{2}  = 136 = \sum c_i$

Because $n$ is an integer I use the floor $n_1=11 \cdot 1726$ and $n_2= -12 \cdot 1726$

But $n$ must be integer, and I cannot see how can I solve the problem in a different way. I will appreciate if someone know how.Thanks a lot!

Comment: The maximum will happen when $c_1=c_2=...=c_n$ by $AM-GM$.

Comment: You say the $c_i$ are real numbers. Then there is no max, for we can choose $n=3$, one of the $c_i$ arbitrarily large negative, another equal to $-1$, and the other so that the sum  is $136$.  Do you want the $c_i$ positive? Or maybe even positive integers?

Comment: ci are any positive real number, n varies over all positive integers and I need to find the maximum over all the possible product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question means $n$ is a variable instead of a given value, assuming $c_i$s are positive we are essentially finding the $n$ that maximizes $({136\over n})^n$ as all $c_is$ are equal by $AMGM$.

$n$ must be less than 136 as larger $n$ will generate product less than $1$. The numerator of the derivative is $136^nln(136)(n^n)-136^nn^n(ln(n)+1)$. Letting it be $0$ we have $ln(136)-ln(n)-1=0$ where $n={136\over e}$. This is the only local maximum as it is the only solution to derivative equals $0$.

We test the two closest integers to $136\over e$, $50$ and $51$ and find out $n=50$ maximizes the result.

Comment: I'm tring to make more clear my statment, with the next: ci are any positive real number, n varies over all positive integers and I need to find the maximum over all the possible product. Extra: I'm sorry for my ignorance but what means AMGM?. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: If that is the problem then my solution solves it. $AM-GM$ is the inequality for positive real numbers that $c_1+c_2+...+c_n \geq {^n\sqrt{c_1c_2...c_n}}$

Comment: Thanks. If n=50, are there any way to know how can I find the value of the maximum product c^50?? ( ci are equal by AM-GM).

Comment: To calculate the actual value of $({136\over50})^{50}$, I believe you have to use a calculator...